# Why am I getting a reference error in my simple module es6 import?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, module

Here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Import Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onClick="show()">Show</button>
<p id="output"></p>
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my script.js

```
import { myString } from "./mod.js";

function show() {
import { myString } from "./mod.js";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
}
```

and here's my mod.js

```
export const myString = "How you like me now?!";
```

On my terminal (I'm running Kali Linux, and viewing the web page via Firefox)
I've done:

"sudo apt install nodejs npm"

and then I navigated over to /Desktop/Gangs of LA/Version 0.3/Module Practice
which contains index.html, script.js and mod.js

and did:
"http-server"

I clear my browsers cache, opened the link from the terminal that http-server provides, clicked the button and boom, nothing shows and I get:

Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined
onclick http://127.0.0.1:8080/:1
127.0.0.1:8080:1:1
onclick http://127.0.0.1:8080/:1

Any help would be appreciate guys :(. It can't possibly be this hard to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Functions in modules are not global. You can't reference them in HTML just like that. Use `window.show = show` after the function

Comment: Also, nodejs or npm has nothing to do with it

Comment: @Konrad …or even better, attach the event handler using `document.querySelector('button').onclick = show` instead of using an `onclick` html attribute

Answer (score 0):

Heavily modified for the sandbox but, you want to assign an object against the window from INSIDE your module. then you can call the code INSIDE the module by referencing the window object.

```js
myString = 'testing';
// set an object against the window
window.MyModule = {
  show: function() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = myString;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Import Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="window.MyModule.show()">Show</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
</body>

</html>
```